# Types incompatible for function parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const a: Test = {
    as: (d: Dust) => {
        return d.b;
    }
};
interface Test {
    as: (d: Tust) => void;
}

interface Tust {
    a: string;
}

interface Dust extends Tust {
    b: boolean;
}
```

Ignore the interface names, this generates a warning:

> Type '(d: Dust) => Dust' is not assignable to type '(d: Tust) =>
> void'.   Types of parameters 'd' and 'd' are incompatible.

But it works, how is the right way to do it to prevent the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Valid error from TypeScript. Here's why:

```
const a: Test = {
    as: (d: Dust) => { // Error: you cannot accept Dust for a Tust
        return d.b;
    }
};
interface Test {
    as: (d: Tust) => void;
}

interface Tust {
    a: string;
}

interface Dust extends Tust {
    b: boolean;
}

// Why: Because it can be called with Tust
a.as({
    a: 'okay' // Allowed
})
```

> how is the right way to do it to prevent the error.

Accept a `Tust` instead of `Dust`.

Comment: but then I won't be able to return `b` which is a property from Dust (I should've thought of more meaningful names) sry about that.